# What kind of field is denoted by $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$?

Tags: vector-spaces, field-theory

For a homework question I have to prove whether or not some set is a vector space over a field $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$, but I am not sure what this notation means and the textbook doesn't seem to clarify. Sorry if that is a pretty basic question!

---

EDIT: I got confused, the field is $\mathbb{Z}_2$, it seems that $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$ in my case denotes the set of all vectors of length $n$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Thanks for the help!

Comment: That set seems to denote the set of all $\;n-$wise component vectors with elements from the field with two elements. That is not a field, though there is a field with $\;p^n\;,\;n\in\Bbb N\;,\;\;p$ any prime...

Comment: But even $\mathbb Z_{2^n}$ would usually be the integers modulo $2^n$ which is different from the finite field $\mathbb F_{2^n}$ when $n>1$.

Comment: I edited the original post to address this. The problem was that the exercise wasn't in LaTeX and I got confused at the very beginning.

Comment: It shouldn't be the length of the vector in that case, but the dimension or number of coordinates.

Comment: That's what I meant, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a finite field of order 2^n. You can make these types of fields for all p^n, for p a prime.

Some definitions and examples are available at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field